# Extending adesigns EventEntity class

Tags: php, symfony, fullcalendar, sonata-admin

Hello guys i'm newbie on Symfony and making a web using sonata admin bundle. I wanted to add event on [adesigns calendar bundle](https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle) from sonata admin but when i extend [EventEntity](https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle/blob/master/Entity/EventEntity.php) class and try to add new event, it gave me below error:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to
>   AppBundle\Entity\Schedule::__construct() must be an instance of
>   DateTime, none given, called in /path/to/project/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Model/ModelManager.php
>   on line 509

I know it causes type of DateTime, but i don't know how to solve it.

Here's the extended code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity\EventEntity;

/**
 * Schedule
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="schedule")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ScheduleRepository")
 */
class Schedule extends EventEntity {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var  string
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var  string
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @var  string
     * @ORM\Column(name="bgColor", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $bgColor;

    /**
     * @var  string
     * @ORM\Column(name="fgColor", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $fgColor;

    /**
     * @var  string
     * @ORM\Column(name="cssClass", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $cssClass;

    /**
     * @var  bool
     * @ORM\Column(name="allDay", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $allDay;

    /**
     * @var  DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="startDatetime", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $startDatetime;

    /**
     * @var  DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="endDatetime", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $endDatetime;

    public function __construct($title, \DateTime $startDatetime, \DateTime $endDatetime = null, $allDay = false, $hall) {
        parent::__construct($title, $startDatetime, $endDatetime, $allDay);
        $this->hall = $hall;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to extend a Doctrine entity [not designed for that](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) you will encounter problems.

You should use [an event listener or a subscriber class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you show me an example? I can't figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: There is an example in the Symfony doc I pointed out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#configuring-the-listener-subscriber